# AppBar leading doesn't show the widgets properly in Flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-appbar

I have a page in which I have an `AppBar` which in turn has an `IconButton` as its `leading` property. The code is as follows:

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        leading: IconButton(
          onPressed: () {},
          icon: const Icon(Icons.arrow_back_ios_new),
          style: IconButton.styleFrom(
            backgroundColor: primary,
            foregroundColor: white,
            shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8),
            ),
          ),
        ),
        title: Text(
          'New Note',
          style: Theme.of(context)
              .textTheme
              .headlineMedium!
              .copyWith(color: primary),
        ),
      ),
    );
}
```

And this is what it looks like (which is normal and the way I want it):

[image]

But when I extract the `IconButton` to a new widget and then use it as the `leading`, it looks different (larger) than before. The code is as follows:

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        leading: NoteButton(    // <--------- Here a custom widget is used
          onPressed: () {},
          icon: const Icon(Icons.arrow_back_ios_new),
        ),
        title: Text(
          'New Note',
          style: Theme.of(context)
              .textTheme
              .headlineMedium!
              .copyWith(color: primary),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

class NoteButton extends StatelessWidget {
  const NoteButton({
    super.key,
    required this.icon,
    required this.onPressed,
  });

  final Widget icon;
  final VoidCallback onPressed;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return IconButton(
      onPressed: onPressed,
      icon: icon,
      style: IconButton.styleFrom(
        backgroundColor: primary,
        foregroundColor: white,
        shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

This is what it looks like:

[image]

As you can see, the button now looks larger than before.

Could you please tell me how to make this custom button (`NoteButton`) look normal as before? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrap your custom widget `NoteButton` with

> `Padding` 8 all side

```
class NoteButton extends StatelessWidget {
  const NoteButton({
    super.key,
    required this.icon,
    required this.onPressed,
  });

  final Widget icon;
  final VoidCallback onPressed;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8),
      child: IconButton(
        onPressed: onPressed,
        icon: icon,
        style: IconButton.styleFrom(
          backgroundColor: Colors.orangeAccent,
          foregroundColor: Colors.white,
          shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

with above code i could solve the issue you are facing

Reason can be:

> by default IconButton has 8 padding to all side so when you use it directly as `leading` that will be applied but when you make it custom widget `NoteButton` as `StatelessWidget` widget it might take padding of `NoteButton`

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
class MyWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        leading: NoteButton(
          // <--------- Here a custom widget is used
          onPressed: () {},
          icon: const Icon(Icons.arrow_back_ios_new),
        ),
        title: Text(
          'New Note',
          style: Theme.of(context)
              .textTheme
              .headlineMedium!
              .copyWith(color: primary),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class NoteButton extends StatelessWidget {
  const NoteButton({
    super.key,
    required this.icon,
    required this.onPressed,
  });

  final Widget icon;
  final VoidCallback onPressed;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SizedBox(
      height: 10,
      width: 10,
      child: IconButton(
        onPressed: onPressed,
        icon: icon,
        style: IconButton.styleFrom(
          backgroundColor: primary,
          foregroundColor: white,
          shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Replace the build method with this and you can change the height and width of the sizedbox according to your need.